# How to import and play an animated 3D file with away3D 4.0 broomstick?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, 3d, away3d

What's the best 3D format to use with away3D for animations ?
And how use it ?

Answer (score 1):

All the file formats supported are listed in the documentation for loaders: http://away3d.com/livedocs/3.5.0_lib/away3d/loaders/package-detail.html

Collada is the best format to use for skeletal animation, but Collada exporters can sometimes be finicky so the simplest format for animated 3D models is md2.

Comment: Note that these docs are for 3.5 not 4.0 and they are two very different versions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but note also that the latest stable release is 3.6, which is mostly the same as 3.5. Any newer versions are unstable trunks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I work with the new Molehill 4.0 Broomstick.
There is a ColladaParser & a MD2Parser, I don't really understand how use them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That doesn't really change my answer about which file formats to use, but you will want to avoid looking too deeply in that specific documentation. If you are having trouble loading a model, well that's a different question (make sure to post your code.)

Comment: Incidentally a couple resources that are probably not directly about version 4 but may help you anyway are http://www.flash-3d.net/2010/11/loading-complex-models-with-away3d/ http://jasonbejot.com/load-and-animate-an-md2-model-in-away3d

Comment: I loaded my .dae file with :

public var cont:ObjectContainer3D = ObjectContainer3D(ResourceManager.instance.parseData(new Test(),"../bin/",true,ColladaParser));

(Test is a .dae class embedded)

Whan I render the 3DView, I see no 3D item and there is no error msg.
But it work with *.obj file.

So the ColladaParser paste nothing at all in my ObjectContainer3D...

Anybody know why ?

Answer (score 0):

In Away3D 4.0 you can use **MD5** (supports skeleton-based animation, more about this format on modwiki.net) **MD2** (supports frame-based animation more about this format on wikipedia) or **AWD** (supports skeleton-based animation, more about this format on code.google).
I can't answer you which is better. Both have pros and cons. Read about differences [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/270665-keyframe-or-skeletal-animation---whats-the-difference/).

You can find code examples on [Away3D 4.0 github project site](https://github.com/away3d/awayphysics-examples-fp11)